# safe C programming

Tags: c, memory

I've noticed that my C compiler (gcc) will let me do stuff like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    short m[32768];
    short y = -1;
    short z = -1;
    printf("%u\n", y);
    m[y] = 12;
    printf("%d\n%d\n", y, m[z]);
}
```

When I run it it spits out:

```
4294967295
12
12
```

Which seems a little baffling to me.

First of all, is it safe for me to run programs like this? Is there any chance I might accidentally write over the operating system (I'm running OS X in case it's relevant)?

Also, I had expected at least some kind of segfault error like I have encountered in the past,  but quietly ignoring an error like this really scares me. How come this program doesn't segfault on me?

And finally, out of curiosity (this might be the silliest question), is there a method to the madness? Can I expect all ANSI C compilers to work this way? How about gcc on different platforms? Is the layout of memory well defined that it is exploitable (perhaps if you were out to write cross-platform obfuscated code)?

Comment: Am I the only one who read the title and went "Safe C programming? What's that??"  :)

Comment: m[-1] is dangerous. NEVER DO THAT

Comment: What do you see when you compile with hints and warnings enabled (`-Wall` for gcc, IIRC)?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: `m[-1]` can be safe if `m` points to an element of an array other than the first element. However in OP's code that's not the case.

Comment: @KenWhite I tried -Wall and I got some warning about main not returning anything. After I changed "main" to "int main" and added a "return 0;" at the end, I didn't get any warnings

Comment: 4294967295 is the equivalent of xFFFFFFFF unsigned

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The C language defines the behavior of certain programs as "undefined".  They can do anything.  We'll call such programs erroneous.

One of them is a program that accesses outside the declared/allocated bounds of an array, which your program *very* carefully does.

You program is erroneous; the thing your erroneous program happens to do is what you see :-}  It could "overwrite the OS"; as a practical matter, most modern OSes prevent you from doing that, but you can overwrite critical values in your process space, and your process could crash, die or hang.

The simple response is, "don't write erroneous programs".  Then the behavior you see will make "C" sense.

In this particular case, with your particular compiler, the array indexing "sort of" works: you index outside the array and it picks up *some* value.  The space allocated to m is in the stack frame; m[0] is at some location in the stack frame and so is "m[-1]" based on machine arithmetic combining the array address and the index, so a segfault does not occur and a memory location is accessed.  This lets the compiled program read and write that memory location ... as an erroneous program.  Basically, compiled C programs don't check to see if your array access is out of bounds.

Our [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety) tool when applied to this program will tell you the array index is illegal at execution time.   So, you can either eyeball the program yourself to see if you've made a mistake, or let CheckPointer tell you when you make a mistake.  I strongly suggest you do the eyeballing in any case.

Comment: @KenWhite: Actually, to quibble, I think the C standard doesn't define your program to be legal upto the point of an undefined operation.  It simply says the behavior of the program is undefined.  That means in some sense, it doesn't have to run at all :-}

Comment: All: I revised my answer to distinguish between the program code, and undefined behaviour of erroneous programs.

Comment: :-) That was my suggestion in the first place. +1, BTW.

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in INRIA's [CompCert C](http://compcert.inria.fr/download.html), a formally, mathematically verifiable and verified implementation of the C language. It's the same authors as the famous [Coq proof assistant](https://coq.inria.fr/). There is also another variante [Verifiable C](https://vst.cs.princeton.edu/).

I don't know much about it, but I know that plane engineers in France use it to program the upcoming embedded computers in planes, so at least in France it's an officially accepted language for critical systems programming.

Lastly, note that a formally verifiable language is different from a safe language.

For example, MISRA C is said to be a safe C language (although this is debated), and there are also [Safe-C](http://www.safe-c.org/start.html), Microsoft's [Checked-C](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/checked-c/) and [Cyclone](https://cyclone.thelanguage.org/), along with safe libraries without changing the compiler such as [Safe C Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/safeclib/) and [libsrt](https://github.com/faragon/libsrt), or just using the standard compiler and libraries but with a sourcecode analyzer such as [frama-c](https://frama-c.com/).

But although safe languages provide fixes to some issues like buffer overflows but no guarantee of consistent logic flow as is needed for critical systems. For example, CompCert C should always produce the same set of Assembler instructions for the same C instructions. Formally verifiable language such as CompCert C and Ada provide such formal guarantees.

You may also be interested in these articles:

- [What's the Difference Between Sound and Unsound Static Analysis?](https://www.electronicdesign.com/embedded-revolution/whats-difference-between-sound-and-unsound-static-analysis)
- [A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, Part 1](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)
- https://github.com/stanislaw/awesome-safety-critical

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, is it safe for me to run programs like this?

Your example: No. Absolutely not. Why would you even try? What are you expecting it to do?
More generic examples using negative indexes - as long as they dereference into legal memory then it's ok.

> Also, I had expected at least some kind of segfault error like I have
>   encountered in the past, but quietly ignoring an error like this
>   really scares me. How come this program doesn't segfault on me?

Blind luck. (actually not excatly - as nicely explained by Ira Baxter)

> And finally, out of curiosity (this might be the silliest question),
>   is there a method to the madness?

If you setup pointers to stuff inside arrays, then negative indexes may work, but they would be a nightmare for others to understand and maintain! - I've seen it done in embedded systems.

> Can I expect all ANSI C compilers to work this way?

Yep.

> How about gcc on different platforms?

Yep

> Is the layout of memory well defined that it is exploitable (perhaps
>   if you were out to write cross-platform obfuscated code)?

Yep - but I'm not sure if you would really want to rely on it.

Comment: Re layout of memory, isn't [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) specifically designed to make a process's address space unpredictable?

Comment: One case where `p[-1]` seems natural is where `p` is a pointer into some data that you are parsing and you need some look-behind information. I find that neater than `*(p-1)` - especially if I'm using the brackets notation for accesses in front of the cursor.

Comment: seriously?  eww, no.  syntactically confusing.  I wouldn't want to come in after a coder who did that. *p is much clearer.

Comment: No, the memory layout is not well defined; you could not rely on it.

Comment: If you are willing to write "p--" anywhere in your program, then "p[-1]" is just fine in those same places.  It is even legitimate to write "T m[k]; p=m[-1];" because the C standard lets you index "one past" the end of the array, and array indexing is defined as addition, in this case as "&m-1".  What it doesn't let you do is go indirect on such a pointer.

Comment: ... I think I should have written "T=m[k]; p=&m[-1];".   The "p=m[1]" is an indirection access beyond the array boundary.  (Better late than never?)

Answer (score 1):

- "Safe", from the standpoint of possibly damaging the OS -- yes, mostly,  Most "modern" operating systems implement some form of "storage protection" so that a wayward or malicious program cannot do bad things to the OS or other programs.  (But the "mostly" indicates that no software longer than 50 lines is perfect and there's always the odd chance that you'll find a chink in the armor.)
- "Safe" from the standpoint of your program "behaving" properly?  Welllllllll, no, mostly.  Here the "mostly" relates to the fact that knowledgeable (I won't say "clever") programmers will occasionally do "strange" things such as using a negative array index, when they know how the compiler and runtime operate and need to efficiently accomplish something that's somewhat outside the norm.  But they (hopefully) do this knowing that the "trick" they're using is very system/compiler-dependent.

But as @jb indicated "safe C programming" is an oxymoron.

Comment: Safe C programming is not an oxymoron. It can be difficult. Designing and manufacturing a safe car is difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: @Reinderien -- So someone is producing a car that won't run into other cars?  Won't run down pedestrians?

Comment: The metaphor breaks down if you try to over-extend it, but essentially, both C programming and many types of engineering exhibit similar characteristics - high complexity, high exposure to risk, potential for high performance and power.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I would suggest that programs that are run against valgrind stand a much better chance of being detected as erroneous than programs that are let loose based upon compiler and OS trust alone. Valgrind won't catch everything, but does a reasonable job in detecting accesses to uninitialized or out-of-bounds memory.

Comment: I don't think valgrind can detect the bug in this particular program.  He's accessing a valid place in his stack frame, which valgrind thinks is OK.  In particular, valgrind won't detect an erroneous access outside of any variable (array, struct member, ...) if that access is still inside the allocated storage containing it (e.g., stack frame, global variable, or heap allocated item).  [CheckPointer *will* detect such errors, even in thread local storage]

Answer (score -1):

If the program requests a legal address in memory (which m[-1] *might* do since its behaviour is undefined), you will not get a segfault...especially if you're asking for a short since it will fit inside most word lengths.  That's a really bad idea, you could easily overwrite something on disk, although the kernel is protected unless you run your code right at startup.

I'm not sure why you printed out the address of -1 though.

Comment: Uh, no, accessing invalid memory on a modern operating system will never cause writes to disk, kernel panic, or indeed anything outside its own memory space without special attention to segmentation rules.

Comment: never is a strong word.  I've done it.  buffer overflow is real.  especially in C.

Comment: Yes, but in a *modern* operating system you will find it very hard to write outside of your program's virtual memory, and quite a lot of intention goes into code that writes to disk.